# Kosaraju's algorithm's time complexity

Tags: algorithm-analysis, graphs, runtime-analysis

I've reading up on Kosaraju's algorithm to compute the strongly connected components of a directed graph and I found that

1. using an adjacency list representation gives a time complexity of $\Theta(V+E)$.
2. using an adjacency matrix representation gives a time complexity of $O(V^{2})$.

Why $\Theta$ in the first case and $O$ in the second case?

Comment: Can you give the reference to the analysis ?

Comment: Here it is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm#Complexity

Comment: @failexam Please include that in the question. You may also want to check the references Wikipedia lists, or find the analyses on Google Scholar.

Answer (score 2):

Any algorithm for computing strongly connected components must examine at least $\binom{|V|}{2}$ entries in the worst case (proof below). In particular, since Kosaraju's algorithm is correct, its (worst-case) complexity is $\Omega(|V|^2)$, and so also $\Theta(|V|^2)$. There is no particular reason why Wikipedia used big O for one and bit $\Theta$ for the reader – probably a different author.

Edit: One possible reason for using big O rather than big $\Theta$ is that sometimes the algorithm is lucky and runs faster. Whether this happens or not could depend on the particular implementation of DFS.

Suppose $A$ is an algorithm examining less than $\binom{|V|}{2}$ entries. We will show that the algorithm cannot always know what the strongly connected components are. Run the algorithm, and for each entry of the adjacency matrix queried by the algorithm, return $0$. When the argument terminates, there are more than $\binom{|V|}{2}$ off-diagonal entries not queried, and in particular there exist vertices $i \neq j$ so that neither the $(i,j)$ nor the $(j,i)$ entry are queried. We could complete the adjacency matrix in two different ways: the all zeroes matrix, or the one in which both these entires are $1$. In the former case, there are $n$ connected components, in the latter, only $n-1$.

Comment: So, you mean that, for this particular case, big omega and big oh are the same, so they give the same big theta?

Comment: They are definitely the same in the worst-case. Perhaps on some graphs the algorithm runs faster, depending on the implementation of DFS, though for most implementations that probably doesn't happen.